# SpringBoot 2.x metrics with histogram timer

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, prometheus, micrometer

Before the introduction of `Micrometer` as the underlying metric provider in `SpringBoot`, it was pretty straight forward to create your own `Timer` meters which published histograms, with predefined bucket sizes etc., just by using the `Timer.builder()` pattern. It seems that after SpringBoot 2.x, I am no longer able to define my own bucket bounds in a histogram. All I can find is a way to tell SpringBoot to publish a percentile histogram, which I have no control over. The percentile histogram for the auto-configured `http.server.request` metric does pretty much every thing I want, except that it has way too many buckets for my use case. I have looked all over for an explanation of how I can configure at least the minimum and maximum values of this metric, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

If anyone has any insight in how to configure the percentile histogram for a `Timer`, or if there is a way to combine buckets directly in `Prometheus`, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: did you found any other solution for this ? other than drop ?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround (not solution, but may be enough) for your specific problem (namely too many buckets) is to filter out the buckets you don't want at scrape time in your Prometheus configuration: https://www.robustperception.io/dropping-metrics-at-scrape-time-with-prometheus/

You would have to use something along these lines (haven't tested it):

```
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: 'my_job'
   static_configs:
     - targets:
       - my_target:1234
   metric_relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [ __name__, le ]
     regex: 'http\.server\.request_buckets;(0.1|0.5|1.0)'
     action: drop
```

This should (again, not tested) drop all the `le="0.1"`, `le="0.5"` and `le="1.0"` buckets. This is entirely safe to do with Prometheus histograms, whether the buckets are at the end of the range or in the middle, because the buckets are cumulative, i.e. the `le="1.0"` bucket counts all occurrences of values `< 1.0`.

Comment: I agree that this should not be the solution, but it seems like a good way to deal with this exact problem with too many buckets. However, I know that we have situations where we are interested in specific buckets, so I definitely think it should be possible to manipulate what the application exports in the first place. Thanks for the workaround.